# Two Models or One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the moment, I have three Models:

```
Users, Applications, Permissions
```

Every User has some Default Permissions:

```
eg: Saving something to Disk
    Deleting something from Disk 
    etc (all permissions are booleans)
```

Every Application Requires A list of permissions. If those permissions are not set TRUE for Default permissions the Application requests those permissions.

So from this:

In Permission.rb I have:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :application
```

Is it better to spit the Permission Model to 2 parts (App_Permissions, Default_Permissions) or do you suggest something more clever (Because the saved Object for Default Permissions will have a nul value of application_id)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't use any model if it's just meant to store booleans.

You could add has many boolean values in a single column of your table, see [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association).

When it comes to default values, I have two approaches:

- adding default values in migrations
- creating a constant and initializing objects with it's values

I prefer the second option but I'd not use a `Default` model unless it has to be changed dynamically by the site admins.

Comment: What if you had some strings as well?

Comment: I don't understand `Because the saved Object for Default Permissions will have a nul value of application_id`

Comment: If I have a Permission model with belongs_to :user
belongs_to :permission doesn't that mean that I will have user_id and application_id fields? For Default Permissions the application_id will be null.

Comment: in `Permission` model, you have `belongs_to :permission` ? problem here

Comment: `I prefer the second option but I'd not use a Default model unless it has to be changed dynamically by the site admins` but the user can obviously change those defaults values...

Comment: ok thanks. If I wanted to continue with only 1a model, leaving app_id empty. Will i have encountered any problems in the future?

Comment: Reconsidering my first shot: Well, to avoid too many db queries, I'd keep the permissions merged in one model.

Comment: @ntenisOT let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1336/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-ntenisot)

Comment: there is no reason to have problems: you master your code. Simply write it in your doc

Comment: I am talking to you to the chat room. Because I actually believe that your proposed solution is much much better.